# How to join only two objects to create a new object using Python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects

I have a total of 7 objects with the 'Cube' as my active object -

```
'Cube', 'Camera', 'Light', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

My main objective is to join A, B, C, D between them and create new objects. It is more like a combination problem. Thus, I will have six NEW joined objects along with the previous 7.

```
AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD
```

I am getting the objects of my interests by the following way

```
obs = [e for e in bpy.data.objects if e.type == 'MESH' and e != bpy.data.objects['Cube']]

# deselect every active object first
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Now I have the objects and every active object deselected, how can I join two objects at a time without deleting or joining on the original objects?

Blender Version: 2.83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work only if all your objects share the same origin and have their transforms applied. Otherwise you will have to convert them using their transform matrices.

Similar to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50186/86891).

We will use `itertools`and `itertools.combinations` to generate the wanted combinations.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

[image]

Then use the `bmesh` module to concatenate the meshes. (Very important that all transforms be applied and origin at 0,0,0 !)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import itertools

objects = bpy.context.selected_objects # Replace with your objects
objects_combinations = itertools.combinations(objects, 2)

for perm in enumerate(objects_combinations):
    this_perm = perm[1]
    new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(this_perm[0].name + this_perm[1].name)
    
    new_bm = bmesh.new()
    new_bm.from_mesh(this_perm[0].data)
    new_bm.from_mesh(this_perm[1].data)
    new_bm.to_mesh(new_mesh)

    new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(this_perm[0].name + this_perm[1].name, new_mesh)
    
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_obj)

    new_bm.free()
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: it worked without any issues. Thanks